# What is the difference between iostream , stdio.h and conio.h header files in c++?

Tags: c++, header-files

I am confused between all these three header files.I read it in Balagurusamy for C++ that all these files are used for taking input and output .But what is the difference.I know that we use stdio.h for scanf and printf and we use iostream for cin and cout.But what is the use of conio.h

Comment: The use of conio.h is for stagnant educators who once did a crash course on teaching C++ in 1985 and have been cashing in on that ever since. It's all in the name, really.

Comment: See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Comment: The biggest thing is that there is no "conio.h" header file in standard C++.

Comment: But why my question is being made unuseful ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Annex D calling...

Comment: @samarthkejriwal  Lack of research - 2 mins on Google would have found my link above

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg But to use scanf and printf we use include stdio.h file in our code.

Comment: @samarthkejriwal - `C` not `C++` functions from deprecated header files.

Comment: @samarthkejriwal For that you should really use `<cstdio>` not the old C standard header file `<stdio.h>`. There is a difference between them. On the other hand, why would you use the old C I/O functions in C++?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg `scanf` and `printf` decreses the time complexicity at times rather than using `cin` and `cout` .

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Have you tried printing padded hexadecimals mixed with decimals? Sometimes printf is very useful...

Comment: Yes i have written codes and my code was accpeted by using scanf and printf in the desired time rather than using cin and cout.It showed Time Limit Exceeded for using cin and cout

Comment: Please if you think it was a usefuul question .Do rate it useful

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Not wanting to take out a global lock to read a locale might be a reason :-)

Comment: May be possible

Comment: About the Time Limit Exceeded issue, did you use [`std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)?  Unfortunately, this is something you have to do if i/o is time-critical.

Comment: @stefaanv making a fast input output function to take the input  and output solved my issue at that time

Answer (score 8):

`stdio.h`/`cstdio` - standard C input and output , as `printf`, `scanf` , `fprintf` etc.
this API is a C API only and based on stateless functions and structures like `FILE` which hold the state. generally used in a C projects and should be avoided in C++.

`iostream` - standard C++ input and output, contains objects like `cout`, `cin` and `cerr`. works with C++ streams, which are objects that manages IO.
the default IO choice for C++ projects. there is a criticism about some aspects of the C++ IO streams, but C++ IO-Streams are still the default choice for most of the projects.

`conio.h` - stands for "console input/output" , a Windows only header which provides C function for console IO manipulations, like `getch`, `ungetch` etc. I fail to see a modern use of this library.

Comment: conio.h predates windows, and is from MS-DOS - Windows supports it due to backward compatibility to MS-DOS.   `cstdio` is a C++ header which (over-simplistically) provides functions from C's `stdio.h`, but [apart from a few macros] places then in namespace `std`.

Comment: conio talks directly to the hardware, stdio goes through the STDIO traps, so it can be redirected to a file, through a pipe to another program, or even to the serial port. As a result, stdio is line oriented and conio is full screen oriented. So its use is full screen applications that do more than simple line based input and output.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is actually profound. stdio talks to STDIN and STDOUT, so you can redirect output to a file or through a pipe to another program. The DOS implementation of conio does not.

Conio talks directly to the video hardware (although it may use the BIOS traps), and so it is faster, and it generally ignores terminal sequences, like ANSI escape sequences. With direct cursor control and a few other things lacking in the generic stdio, conio is much more usful for writing full screen interactive programs that use color, mouse, and line drawing symbols for GUI-like programs.